# Is it permissible for me to take out a bank loan to help someone, if I'm not the one paying off the interest?

Tags: halal-haram, riba

I know that *riba* is *haram* in Islam. However, I need to know if it would actually be *haram* for me to take bank loan for helping my friend who is in a pathetic condition, if the monthly loan and everything (i.e. the interest on the loan) will be paid by him and not myself.

Comment: Have you red the last portion of it "they are all alike". This answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a hadith of the Prophet (S.A.W) that buttresses the invalidity in *riba* in whatever circumstances:

> Jabir b. Abdullah reports that the Prophet (S.A.W) cursed the 
>   receiver of interest and the payer thereof, the one who  records it
>   and the two witnesses thereof.
>
> He said: "They are  all alike [in guilt]."
>   <sup>[Muslim, Tirmidhi, Ahmad]</sup>

As seen in the Hadith above, all parties involved in *riba* are guilty in the Book of Allah (S.W.T)

Comment: Most of this answer is wholly irrelevant to the question, since all it is doing is establishing that *riba* is *haram*, a fact which the questioner is already well-aware of according to his own question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not okay. Unless it is absolute dire situation (death) depending on it or some other serious situation you cannot break the rules. 
If the person is in need, then help him with your own money, ask others to help him, but RIBA is forbidden. Unless it was a super-serious situation (life and death) and there were no other options. But if it is to get a better car, to have a better standard of living, to look better, all these are trivial things when it comes to religion and breaking rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ok.  Paying of interest should not prevent you from doing a good deed. Remember paying of interest is like paying rent on the use of someone's money.  It is not intended to leave the borrower in poverty by charging unreasonable interest rate.  In this day and age paying rent for using other's money is common.But if someone charges 30 or 40% interest that would be against the ethics of any society because the intent is to take advantage of the needy. That is not allowed.